# Windows Server CAL for IIS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, cal

I have read numerous articles (and ServerFault answers) on CAL licencing, and thought I understand it. My understanding so far was that CAL licenses are related to users and devices directly accessing the server, i.e. ones which are using it **within the network**, similar to logging on to the server, using its print/file services, or otherwise accessing its services inside the company.

But according to this [TechNet article about CAL licensing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/volume-licensing/archive/2014/03/10/licensing-how-to-when-do-i-need-a-client-access-license-cal.aspx):

> **Do I need a CAL when my Windows Server is used to run a web server?**
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 configured to run *Web Workloads* **do not require** CALs or External Connectors.  Web workloads, also referred to as an internet web solution, are publicly accessible (e.g. accessible outside of the firewall) and consist only of web pages, web sites, web applications, web services, and/or POP3 mail serving.  Access to content, information, and/or applications within the internet web solution must be publicly accessible.  In other words, they cannot be restricted to you or your affiliate’s employees.
>
> If you have Windows Servers configured to run a “web workload” these users will **not require** CALs or External Connectors.
>
> However, let’s say you are using Windows Server to setup an online store where customers can buy *widgets*.  You have front end Windows Servers setup to support your website, and back-end servers (e.g. commerce servers) setup so customers can check out and buy your widgets.  The front end servers used to host your website would generally be considered as running “web workloads” and CALs or External Connectors **will not be required** to access these servers.
>
> Once the customer adds a widget to their shopping cart, creates an account and enters their credit card and shipping information to complete the sale – they are now authenticated via your back end commerce servers/application (non-web workload).  Since users are accessing the back-end commerce servers which web workloads are not running – CALs or External Connectors **will be required** for users to access these back end servers.

For me, the process of "creating an account and entering payment/shipping information" is confined to IIS. Does this mean the owner of the Windows Server machine needs to purchase as many CALs as there are users accessing "non-publicly available content"?

**Does a Windows Server running IIS must really have a separate CAL for each physical user which has a web page account?**

Comment: While I fully agree with the proposed answer that "Licensing is a hard and absolutely vendor-specific problem", I don't see why hard and vendor-specific problems can't be answered. I see them being answered every day on Stack Overflow. Is there really a licensing expert here who can confirm that the answer to *whether you need CAL licenses for IIS users* is a "complex, region-dependent, company-size-dependant, multi-variable puzzle" instead of being a simple yes/no answer? Especially since Iain and @EEAA seem to be specialized in Linux?

Comment: No, we don't do licensing questions. If you ask three MS licensing "experts" a question, you will likely get three different answers. Many vendors can't even get their own story together. Additionally, licensing terms vary depending on where you live and a dozen other points. This is not a MS vs. Linux thing. I would close a Linux licensing question just as quickly as I did this one. You'll need to engage your vendor here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but *If you ask three MS licensing "experts" a question, you will likely get three different answers* - if this is a known fact outside ServerFault? I am aware neither your or any other person on SF (or the internet for that matter) is obliged to provide any sources to their claims, but is it possible to back this claim, Wikipedia-style? And if yes, does this really cover *any* question regarding licensing? Also, I have read FAQ and I am aware that licensing is off-topic here, but I have a feeling that this rule is perhaps being applied too strictly.

Comment: My citation: 15 years of industry experience in multi-OS, multi-platform environments. If you think the rule is being applied in too strict a fashion, you're always free to post your reasoning on meta.serverfault.com. If enough of the community agrees with you, we can change the rule.